# Table column resize

Tags: html, css

I have such table structure(I can replace with Div if it is possible to solve the problem suing them) and would like to set width of the left column to fixed size in pixels, for example 300px and make right column auto width to keep it resized from left column to the border of browser. My solution do not work in this situation.

```
 <table>
   <tr>
        <td width="300"> 
            fixed size
        </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
        <td width="100%"> 
             take free space
        </td>
   </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: The table in your HTML has only one column..

Comment: It's not clear what you're after. An image would help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using/suing DIVs:

```
<div style="background-color: lime; float: left; width: 300px;">fixed size</div>
<div style="background-color: cyan; margin-left: 300px;">take free space</div>
```

## [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/v5LHP/)

Answer (score 5):

Using a `table`: http://jsfiddle.net/rtVzf/

```
<table width="100%">
   <tr>
        <td width="300"> 
            fixed size
        </td>
        <td> 
            take free space
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try pinning your table to the left and specifying 100%, then making your left column a fixed width, and then pinning your right column to the right.

```
 <TABLE width="100%" height="100%" align="left" border="1">
       <TR>
         <TD width="300px" height="100% align="left" valign="top">
        <p align="left">Get rid of the border by changing it to 0 after you get all of your placement down.</p>
         </TD>
         <!--other TDs if desired-->
         <TD height="100%" align="right" valign="top">
           <p align="left">written stuff or images, etc.</p>
         </TD>
       </TR>
    </TABLE>
```

Answer (score -1):

Your table should also have a width="100%" either through an attribute or through CSS.